# removing duplicates in java on large scale data

Tags: java

I have the following issue.
I'm connecting to some place using and API and getting the data as an inputstream.
the goal is to save the data after removing duplicate lines.
duplication defined by columns 10, 15, 22.

i'm getting the data using several threads.
currently I first save the data into a csv file and then remove duplicates.
I want to do it while i'm reading the data.
the volume of the data is about 10 million records.
I have limited memory that I can use.
the machine has 32gb of memory but I am limited since there are other applications that using it.

I read here about using hash maps.
but I'm not sure I have enough memory to use it.

does any one has a suggestion how to solve this issue?

Comment: Do you have an example of the output given by your API? And is duplication defined by the combination of the three columns (10,15,22) or each of these columns has to be unique without reference to the others?

Comment: the output of the api is a string something like that:
="banna",="orange",="apple"... etc. about 30 elements.

the combination of these columns is the key.

Answer (score 1):

A Hashmap will use up at least as much memory as your raw data. Therefore, it is probably not feasible for the size of your data set (however, you should check that, because if it is, it's the easiest option).

What I would do is write the data to a file or database, compute a hash value for the fields to be deduplicated, and store the hash values in memory with a suitable reference to the file (e.g. the byte index of where the original value is in the written file). The reference should of course be as small as possible.

When you hit a hash match, look up the original value and check whether it is identical (as hashes for different values may fall together).

The question, now, is how many duplicates you expect. If you expect few matches, I would choose a cheap write and expensive read solution, i.e. dumping everything linearly into a flat file and reading back from that file.

If you expect many matches, it's probably the other way round, i.e. having an indexed file or set of files, or even a database (make sure it's a database where write operations are not too expensive).

Comment: what if I hash the key and insert it into a list (or a linkedList) and will check the list if the hash exists if not I will write directly to the target file and if it exists I will ignore?
I except to have about 2 million unique records.

Comment: As @lexicore mentioned, you might have hash collisions, i.e. two different values might have the same hash. If you can come up with a special hash function for your use case which is guaranteed to avoid hash collisions, then you can do what you describe. Otherwise, once you find an identical hash, you have to compare the actual underlying values. 

An exception would be a use case where ommitting some unique entries was acceptable (a rather unusual scenario).

Answer (score 1):

The solution depends on how big is your data in columns 10, 15, 22.

Assuming it's not too big (say, ca. 1kb) you can actually implement an in-memory solution.

- Implement a `Key` class to store values from columns 10, 15, 22. Carefully implement `equals` and `hashCode` methods. (You may also use a normal `ArrayList` instead.)
- Create a `Set` which would contain keys of all records you read.
- For each record you read, check if it's key is already in that set. If yes, skip the record. If not, write the record to output, add the key to the set. Make sure you work with set in a thread-safe manner.

In the worst case you'll need `number of records * size of key` amount of memory. For 10000000 records and the assumed <1kb per key this should work with around 10GB.

If the key size is still too large, you'll probably need a database to store the set of key.

Another option would be storing hashes of keys instead of full keys. This will require much less memory but you may be getting hash collisions. This may lead to "false positives", i.e. false duplicates which aren't actually duplicates. To completely avoid this you'll need a database.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ConcurrentHashSet. it will automatically remove the duplicate element and it's thread safe up to a certain limit

Comment: what is the memory limit?
will it handle the volume of the data I have?